# How to resolve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when connecting to virtualenv/django running on a server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, putty

I have installed virtualenv and Django in my user section on a ubuntu server. Everything appeared to install correctly and when I start the server with `python manage.py runserver` I get the following message, which seems correct:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes,                                                                       sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

January 10, 2019 - 16:38:32
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'form01.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

The problem is when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in my browser I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of the Django install success page.

I expect to see the Django successful install screen at http://127.0.0.1:8000 but instead get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Is the browser running on the same machine as `runserver`?

Comment: @Alasdair the browser is running on my local machine and runserver is on a server

Comment: If you run `python manage.py runserver` then it will only be available from the local server. You could investigate port forwarding using ssh. If you search for accessing Django runserver remotely, you will see suggestions to use `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, but this can make your site accessible to the entire internet, which is not suitable because runserver is not a production server.

Comment: Have you found a fix?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `virtualenv`, it blocks connection somehow (couldn't find it out). I deactivated `virtualenv` and launched the app using `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. The app should be accessible on `http://[ ip ]:8000` where `ip` is the thing returned by `ipconfig getifaddr en0` command.

You can also use `gunicorn` to host the app & `nginx` to deliver static files (as gunicorn doesn't handle that). This will allow to continue use the `virtualenv`, but will bring the need to use some more software.

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me (Django 3.1.6) was to add `'*'` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` in `myproject/setting.py`, **and** starting the server like this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

No other combination of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` worked, not even with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting allowed hosts in settings.py to '*'.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: And also be sure to migrate your data by running 'python manage.py migrate'

Answer (score 0):

If you use 127.0.0.1 on your local machine is that not simply going to be looking for the django installation on you local machine instead of on the server where it is running? Could be why your connection is being refused. 
If you have a browser on your server you should be able to enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/ on the server and see if it returns the Django Successful installation page that you are looking for.
If you don't have a browser installed on the server then I think you'll need to have a settings file in place in an app with an ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] as mentioned above or ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['server ip address'].  Then you should be able to access it from your local machine using http://server ip address:8000/

Comment: I did this and unfortunately I am receiving the same error. Could it be a firewall issue? My local machine is on my employer's network with security measures in place

Comment: I don't think it is a firewall issue because I can access the Apache2 Ubuntu default page at https://(MyServerIPAddress)

Comment: Seems you have an SSL certificate running on the server if https://(MyServerIPAddress) works.  Which might be a part of the issue as to why http://server ip address:8000/ doesn't.  I would suggest you try https://(MyServerIPAddress):8000/ and see what happens.