# curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, djoser

I'm trying to make a Chat application using Django and Vue.js. For this initially I started to create a Django project where I installed Django rest framework and djoser using pip and added corresponding url's in urls.py.

But when I'm trying to create user using [curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/create/ --data] I'm getting as *"curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused"*. Following are the required scripts.

urls.py :

```
    """chatire URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for chatire project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dns*bsa6_2)bbdglt)jj=o-912h6=lyo#7qshl7&htuys%400&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'djoser',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chatire.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'chatire.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: How do you run your project? The `Connection Refused` error shows no process is listening on that port.

Comment: Using the below command I'm running the project-python manage.py runserver ,I dont get an error when I run this,but when I run this ----> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/create/ --data ,I'm getting that error

Comment: Are you sure Django is listening on that port? If you're on Linux, try `sudo netstat -ntlp` and see what port is used by your app.

Comment: No port is not listening. I've checked using netstat -a. I'm using windows by the way. I'm using 8000 port for the project ,but when checked using netstat command, I'm not able to find 8000 port listening.

Comment: Hmmm, are you using WSL for running django or curl?

Comment: I'm using curl not WSL

Comment: I meant if you are using WSL in any of curl or Django. As it seems, your response would be no. Are you using `virtualenv`? There were similar issues here that were related to virtualenv: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169292/8543203. Also try `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to make sure you're binding it to all of ips of your host and on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

open the settings.py file and make these changes

```py
DEBUG = False
 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your Django app should be running when you execute curl**
You can do this by opening a second terminal. In my case I ran `python manage.py runserver` on *cmd* and the curl command on *VS code terminal*.