# Can't reach local server while Django app is running

Tags: python, django, web-applications

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 29, 2021 - 17:45:15
Django version 4.0, using settings 'webapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

but when I try to open it in Chrome I'm only getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Only a few hours ago it worked, I changed nothing.

Comment: Can you paste the full URL you are trying to access in Chrome?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Including the protocol? Is Chrome trying to access over https - `https://127.0.0.1:8000`?

Comment: It just says to check the connection and to check proxy and firewall. Did both changed nothing. Accessing over https didn't work either.

Comment: What is the value of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` ?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting allowed hosts in settings.py to '*'.

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133995/how-to-resolve-err-connection-refused-when-connecting-to-virtualenv-django-runni)

Comment: Did not work, still same issue